# Shell: put data together

Tags: shell

I write  a shell script to put data together.
I have 2 files with different columns.
One of the columns is the same on both of the file.

```
Like :
File 1:
a   5
c   7
d   9
b   5

File 2:
c   1
d   8
a   6
b   3
```

For the moment my script put the data in a same file with

```
paste -d ' ' 'file1'  'file2' > "file3"
```

I would like to know if it's possible to match the 2 columns together and in order like:

```
a   5   6
b   5   3
c   7   1
d   9   8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
sort file1 > file1.tmp
sort file2 > file2.tmp

join -t " " -j 1 file1.tmp file2.tmp
```

Assumed that character and numbers are separated by a SPACE

Answer (score 1):

Using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) you can sort the files and join them in a single command.

```
join -t " " -j 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort` to sort both files, and then `join` to join on the first field.